# Dask: is it safe to pickle a dataframe for later use?

Tags: python, dask

I have a database-like object containing many dask dataframes. I would like to work with the data, save it and reload it on the next day to continue the analysis.

Therefore, I tried saving dask dataframes (not computation results, just the "plan of computation" itself) using pickle. Apparently, it works (at least, if I unpickle the objects on the exact same machine) ... but are there some pitfalls?

Comment: You can unpickle on any machine and get the same result.

Comment: So is it enough to ensure, the data underlying the dataframes are accessible under the same path and then it should be safe?

Comment: Yes, it should be safe. Pickle saves everything you need to restore the object to the same state as it was when it was pickled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking it is *usually* safe.  However there are a few caveats:

1. If your dask.dataframe contains custom functions, such as with with `df.apply(lambda x: x)` then the internal function will not be pickleable.  However it will still be serializable with [cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle)
2. If your dask.dataframe contains references to files that are only valid on your local computer then, while it will still be serializable the re-serialized version on another machine may no longer be useful
3. If your dask.dataframe contains `dask.distributed` `Future` objects, such as would occur if you use `Executor.persist` on a cluster then these are not currently serializable.
4. I recommend using a version >= 0.11.0.

Comment: We have the same use case. Would like to share computations between data scientist within a company. The architecture we are thinking about is pickling the dask dataframes (plan of execution) and storing it pickled in a key value store. It should be executable on a different cluster at a later time. Is point 3 still the case, and if so, could you mentor me towards a PR on this?