# Store a Dask DataFrame as a pickle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a Dask DataFrame constructed as follows:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('matrix.txt', header=None)
type(df) //dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame
```

Is there way to save this DataFrame as a pickle?

For example,

```
df.to_pickle('matrix.pkl')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a quick inspection of the methods available in `dask` that is not directly possible. It's still possible to do as the other answer, but I fear that due to the eventual distributed nature of a dask dataframe it might be not straightforward.

Anyhow, if I were you, I'd go through another solution and use parquet as a storage. It offers you basically the same advantages of pickle, and more.

```
df.to_parquet('my_file.parquet')
```

Although, if your plan is to use pickle as a 'suspend' method to later on resume computation, saving to parquet would not really help.

My advise would be by far to use parquet. Look at this [post](https://tech.blueyonder.com/efficient-dataframe-storage-with-apache-parquet/) where  different technologies to store a general pandas dataframe are compared. You'll see that they don't even discuss pickle (which has some issues like it might be incompatible between two python versions). The article is slightly old, and now pandas/dask can directly work with parquet without the need of explicitly using `pyarrow`.

I guess that you're interested in reading time. There is always a tradeoff between file size and read time. Although in the article is shown that when you factor in multiple core operation you can get similar read performance with compressed parquet file (Parquet-snappy column)

[image]

Thus, I'll repeat myself. Go for `parquet` file and you'll future-proof yourself. Unless that your use case is very different than columnar/dataframe oriented one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The situation is that I have a 20GB matrix which I want to load into a DataFrame. The idea is to be able to save this and load this on demand. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Arjun expanded a bit my answer ;)

Comment: any chance you can get an update on that post? the website is no longer serving that page.

Answer (score 5):

You can try pickling it like you would do with any other object - 
    import pickle

```
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(df, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)
print(a == b)
```

Further, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147916/4098013) on safety of pickling dask dataframes and in what situations in might break